# struct como parámetro de la función quicksort() en C

Tags: c

tengo el siguiente código:

```
typedef struct
{
    char mail[321];
    char domain[256];

}domains;

int compareDomains( const void *, const void * );

int main(void)
{
    domains typeDomain[10000];
    int i ;
    int total = 8;

    // --------------------------Input----------------------

    for (i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++)
        scanf("%255s", typeDomain[i].domain);

    // -----------------------Process-----------------------

    // EN ESTA PARTE TENGO LA DUDA.......
    qsort(typeDomain, total, sizeof(  ), compareDomains);

    printf("\nELEMENTOS ORDENADOS\n\n");

    for (i = 0 ; i < total ; i++)
        printf("%s\n", typeDomain[i].domain);

    return 0;
}

int compareDomains( const void *pivot, const void *element )
{
    char *ptrPivot = (char *) pivot;
    char *ptrElement = (char *) element;
    return strcmp(ptrPivot, ptrElement);
}

En este programa, el objetivo es que el usuario tiene que ingresar los datos de tipo typeDomain[i].domain y luego el programa tiene que ordenar estos elementos en orden creciente. por ejemplo:

input

udec.cl
upla.cl
utfsm.cl
hotmail.com
gmail.com
inf.pucv.cl
gmail.com
inf.pucv.cl

output

ELEMENTOS ORDENADOS


gmail.com
gmail.com
hotmail.com
inf.pucv.cl
inf.pucv.cl
udec.cl
upla.cl
utfsm.cl
```

Mi duda es: ¿Cómo puedo usar `quicksort()`, pero utilizando un parámetro de tipo `struct`?, en el `struct` que hay en el programa se tiene dos campos: `mail` y `domain`...pero solo quiero ordenar los datos `domain`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El argumento que te falta es el tamaño del tipo a comparar:

```
qsort( typeDomain, total, sizeof( domains ), compareDomains );
```

Y tu función de comparación debería quedar así:

```
int compareDomains( const void *pivot, const void *element ) {
  const domains *p = (const domains *)pivot;
  const domains *e = (const domains *)element;

  return strcmp( &( p->domain ), &( e->element ) );
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano, se agradece mucho...Saludos